# Eclipse EPIC - connection timed out error

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, epic

I am puzzled: when I am running EPIC Perl debugging tool it produces "Timed out while waiting for Perl debugger connection" error along with "Unable to connect to remote host: 192.168.1.37:5000
Compilation failed in require...." on the console.

I am on OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan, darwin 15.0), using Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2, EPIC 0.7.0 (same thing happens with 6.5.6), and Perl 5.18 (prebuilt for darwin) or ActiveState Perl 5.20

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found the answer. The IP address mentioned in the error message is the one that I had statically added in the hosts file. For some reasons EPIC searches this address for debugger connection skipping dynamic addressing assigned by DHCP.